# Create category exception when hide out of stock product is enabled woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, product

I am experiencing trouble creating a function that creates a category exception when hide out of stock product is enabled in WooCommerce.

I have variable products categorised to slug 'back-soon'. Some of these may be 'out-of-stock'. I want the out-of-stock products in from category to show, in all categories they're in 'ie new arrivals'.

We have many out-of-stock products that we don't want to show. It is not a matter of unticking hide out of stock. I do apologise, I'm not an advanced code - so not sure where else to look for help.

This code shows the out-of-stock products, but exclusively on the back soon category page.

```
add_filter( 'pre_option_woocommerce_hide_out_of_stock_items', 'bbloomer_hide_out_of_stock_exception_category' );

function bbloomer_hide_out_of_stock_exception_category( $hide ) {
  if ( is_product_category( 'back-soon' ) ) {
     $hide = 'no';
  }  
  return $hide;
}
```

I've also worked with the below code. I've just put bits of code together, I don't even understand it. Sorry for my ignorance.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_is_visible', 'keep_showing_products_in_category', 10, 2);

function keep_showing_products_in_category($visible, $product_id) {
   $category_slug = 'your-category-slug'; // Replace with your category's slug
   $category = get_term_by('slug', $category_slug, 'product_cat');

   if (!$category) {
       return $visible;
   }

   $product_list = get_posts(array(
       'post_type' => 'product',
       'posts_per_page' => -1,
       'tax_query' => array(
           array(
               'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
               'field' => 'term_id',
               'terms' => $category->term_id,
           ),
       ),
   ));

   $product_ids = array();
   foreach ($product_list as $product) {
       $product_ids[] = $product->ID;
   }

   return in_array($product_id, $product_ids) ? true : $visible;
}
```